# Can't install Ubuntu 17.10! It crashes when I try to set Partitions

Tags: system-installation, crash, 17.10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 17.10. But whenever I get to the step that says **Installation Type**, it stops working. As it comes up with a blank table with things like **Mount Point** and **Create New Partition Table** and when I try to press `+`, `-`, or `Change` the system crashes. On runnning the command `sudo parted -l` from Terminal, I get the following output :-

```
Model: SanDisk Cruzer Dial(scsi)
Disk \dev\sda: 31.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:
Number Start End Size Type File System Flags
1 1049kB 31.5GB 31.5GB primary fat32 boot,lba
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> As it comes up with a blank table with things like Mount Point and Create New Partition Table and when I try to press +, -, or Change the system crashes.

I read your question when searching for an answer for my own problem as I noticed the same symptoms when attempting to setup a dual boot configuration on a laptop.

In my case the root cause was that the disk controller (`Intel RST Premium`) implements software RAID and it appears Intel do not make drivers available.

The good news was that I could change the controller to AHCI in the UEFI settings. After this change the installer was able to see the disk and all of its partitions.

A more detailed explanation is in the answer to this question: [Trouble installing ubuntu for dual boot along with win 10. The installation type table is empty](https://askubuntu.com/a/1001122/787798).

---

I am making an assumption the disk is present and will mount on another operating system (i.e. Windows). Ideally I would have preferred to check this with a comment, but unfortunately have sufficient reputation to make a comment.

Comment: I read 17.10 had bugs and you should install 17.10.1 instead.