# Trouble installing Ubuntu for dual boot along with Windows 10. The installation type table is empty

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

Having trouble installing Ubuntu for dual boot along with Windows 10. The installation type table is empty. I have secure boot, hibernation, fast boot disabled, partitioned 20GB for Ubuntu as well. Nothing seems to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and most of the guides I read highlighted the need to disable fast boot and secure boot. Despite disabling both settings neither the installer nor [GParted](https://gparted.org/) would list any of the partitions from the disk on my laptop.

The [Ubuntu 17.10 not recognising a partition set aside for Linux (dual-boot with windows 10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968870/ubuntu-17-10-not-recognizing-a-partition-set-aside-for-linux-dual-boot-with-win#comment1552554_968870) thread discusses `RAID` controllers vs `AHCI` and initially (through my own ignorance) I discounted it as I associated RAID with multiple-disk setups.

I did discover though when looking through the [UEFI Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ5xQ.jpg) that the SATA controller mode was `Intel RST Premium`, which as I understand offers software RAID.

If you find the same then please proceed with the instructions below.

---

High-level the steps are:

1. Switch the controller to AHCI.
2. Ensure Windows has the correct drivers.
3. Install Ubuntu.

This article outlines the process [SOLUTION: Switch Windows 10 from RAID/IDE to AHCI operation](https://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/), but in summary:

1. Switch Windows to safe mode by running `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal` from the cmd prompt as an Administrator.
2. Restart into the UEFI settings and change the controller to `AHCI` instead of `Intel RST Premium`.
3. Restart and ensure Windows boots (*in safe mode*).
4. Disable safe mode by running `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot` (again as an Administrator).
5. Restart again to ensure Windows starts with the `AHCI` drivers.

After this start the Ubuntu installer (as previously) and it should list your drives (hopefully offering the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" option).

---

Some more reading about Intel RST here:

- [If Linux won't install on your laptop, blame Intel not Microsoft](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3123075/linux/linux-wont-install-on-your-laptop-blame-intel-not-microsoft.html)

Comment: I don't know if this answer is right or not, but +1 for a well written, detailed, and easy to understand answer. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: Worked for me. Stupid Intel.