# Ubuntu 18.04 not detecting a partition for installer

Tags: partitioning

I was following the below guide, but when reaching step 6 to allocate drive space, Ubuntu does not seem to detect my hard drive. Below is the screenshot of the drive selection tab. Thanks in advance.
https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5

Laptop

```
Asus Vivobook
Model: X512FA-BI7A
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
```

Additionally, when I try to add a drive or partition during the installer, the installer crashes and references this error

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1064151

[image]

Comment: Does this machine have an existing OS or partiitons? If so, what are they?

Comment: The machine is running a brand new copy of Windows 10 with the default partitions. This is the first time I have booted it up

Comment: Many new systems still need UEFI update & if SSD drive firmware update. You also need to have Windows fast start up off as that sets hibernation flag which prevents Linux NTFS from seeing it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Be sure to boot in UEFI boot mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my drive show up when installing Windows if I change it from RAID to AHCI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001500/will-my-drive-show-up-when-installing-windows-if-i-change-it-from-raid-to-ahci)

Comment: Please don't put solved in your question. Put the detailed solution in **Your Answer** and after the required wait time accept your answer as correct. This will help others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble installing Ubuntu for dual boot along with Windows 10. The installation type table is empty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999934/trouble-installing-ubuntu-for-dual-boot-along-with-windows-10-the-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Go back into Windows, right click on the Windows icon, choose Disk Management, and see if the disc was formatted as a Basic drive or a Dynamic drive.

If the latter, you will need to [convert it back from Dynamic to Basic](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic.html) ([alternate](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-convert-a-dynamic-disk-into-a-basic-disk/)) before you can install Ubuntu or anything else.

**HOWEVER**: Repartitioning a drive is the easiest way to erase everything on it and lose all your data, programs, and operating system. Go carefully; make two backups to external media or the cloud, and verify each before you proceed, unless you are 100% ready to permanently remove Windows and all its data.

Comment: These drives are basic drives

Comment: Drives, plural? Are they in a RAID?

Comment: Drive* Sorry, it it was 1 single drive and partition

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had to change the sata configuration to AHCI from within the BIOS.

Thank you all for your input.